# Reset xrandr (or: switch off the --scale-from setting at disconnect)

Tags: xrandr

I recently found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318580/xrandr-clone-and-scale) topic which helped me a lot by pointing me to the `--scale-from` argument. I'm pretty happy with the way I can connect my projector now and have the same content displayed on both devices without any panning or clipping.
But unfortunately I don't know how to switch the setting off again after I disconnected the projector.

In my example I have my laptop screen (LVDS1 in xrandr) with a resolution of 1366x768 and the projector (VGA1) with a 1280x800 resolution. After I connect the projector I use

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x800 --output LVDS1 --scale-from 1280x800
```

which is inconvenient but at least logical.
But when I disconnect the projector later and want to switch back to only using the laptop screen, I need to do something like

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --off
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale-from 1366x768
xrandr --fb 1366x768
```

which I find very inconvenient. Also I don't know of any possibility to find out if there's a scale-from setting currently in action. So my question is: Is there an easier way for this? Since 1366x768 is the preferred resolution for the laptop screen I would have expected one to exist.

Answer (score 5):

I use this same workflow and stumbled on a solution today. It looks like `--scale` and `--scale-from` are convenience aliases for `--transform` so I think the best way to "reset" these kinds of modifications is by using the flag below:

```
--transform none
```